# Call generic method with class determined at runtime

Tags: java, generics, java-8, jersey-2.0, hk2

I'm trying to automatically bind factory classes with a certain annotation using jersey 2/HK2. Therefore, I get the provided type at runtime from a generic interface and then try to bind the factory to this type. The method that binds the factory to a class looks like this:

```
protected void bindResourceFactory(Class<? extends Factory<?>> factory) {
  Class<?> providedClass = getProvidedClass(factory);
  bindFactory(factory).to(providedClass).in(Singleton.class);
}
```

The `bindFactoy` method provided by HK2 is defined as following:

```
public <T> ServiceBindingBuilder<T> bindFactory(Class<? extends Factory<T>> factoryType) {
    return resetBuilder(AbstractBindingBuilder.<T>createFactoryBinder(factoryType, null));
}
```

This seems to work well when I build everything with eclipse. However when I build the project with maven, I get the following build error:

```
[ERROR] /Users/jan/Documents/Workspace/jersey-test/bind/ResourceFactoryBinder.java:[32,5] no suitable method found for bindFactory(java.lang.Class<capture#1 of ? extends org.glassfish.hk2.api.Factory<?>>)
[ERROR]     method org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder.<T>bindFactory(java.lang.Class<? extends org.glassfish.hk2.api.Factory<T>>,java.lang.Class<? extends java.lang.annotation.Annotation>) is not applicable
[ERROR]       (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
[ERROR]         (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
[ERROR]     method org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder.<T>bindFactory(java.lang.Class<? extends org.glassfish.hk2.api.Factory<T>>) is not applicable
[ERROR]       (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
[ERROR]         (argument mismatch; java.lang.Class<capture#1 of ? extends org.glassfish.hk2.api.Factory<?>> cannot be converted to java.lang.Class<? extends org.glassfish.hk2.api.Factory<T>>))
[ERROR]     method org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder.<T>bindFactory(org.glassfish.hk2.api.Factory<T>) is not applicable
[ERROR]       (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
[ERROR]         (argument mismatch; java.lang.Class<capture#1 of ? extends org.glassfish.hk2.api.Factory<?>> cannot be converted to org.glassfish.hk2.api.Factory<T>))
```

The java version in both cases is 1.8.0_152.

The reason probably is that my argument used is of type `Class<? extends Factory<?>>` whereas `bindFactory` expects `Class<? extends Factory<T>>`. Does someone know, why this might build with eclipse but not with maven? And is there any way to make this work apart from calling `bindFactory` via reflection?

Comment: Well the diference is probably because eclipse uses its own compiler (ECJ) and maven uses java's. If you specify a generic type in bindFactory does it work?, like this<Object>bindFactory(...).

Comment: Good to know! No, that doesn't compile in eclipse or maven: `The parameterized method <Object>bindFactory(Class<? extends Factory<Object>>) of type AbstractBinder is not applicable for the arguments (Class<capture#8-of ? extends Factory<?>>)`

Comment: Mmm that makes sense, try to cast factory  `this.<Object>bindFactory((Class<? extends Factory<Object>>) factory)`. Sorry I don't have eclipse at hand right now.

Comment: Yeah, this works `bindFactory((Class<Factory<Object>>) factory)`!

Comment: Great, I'll post a more detailed answer.

Comment: Well i guess you didn't cast to object after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this error happens is because the compiler doesn't capture convert the "inner" wildcard in `Class<? extends Factory<?>>` (the one in `Factory<?>`). (In terms of the specification, ["capture conversion is not applied recursively"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10).)

It's easier to explain why this should happen with a different (but analogous with respect to the kind of types involved) example. Suppose we have a `List` of any type of `List`:

```
List<List<?>> lists = ...;
```

Now suppose we have some method that processes lists of lists, but assumes that the lists all have the same type:

```
<T> void process(List<List<T>> lists) {
    // and at this point we should note that List<T>
    // allows us to add elements to the lists, so we
    // could do something like this:

    if (!lists.isEmpty()) {
        List<T> list0 = lists.get(0);

        for (int i = 1; i < lists.size(); ++i)
            list0.addAll(lists.get(i));
    }
}
```

So the question is: should we be able to pass our `List<List<?>>` to the `process` method? Well, it could be that we've built our list of lists in something like the following way:

```
List<Double> doubles = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.addAll(doubles, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0);

List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.addAll(strings, "X", "Y", "Z");

List<List<?>> lists = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.addAll(lists, strings, doubles);
```

In that case it's more obvious that we shouldn't be able to pass the `List<List<?>>` to the process method taking a `List<List<T>>`. The way this is actually accomplished by the compiler is that it won't capture the "inner" wildcard to some type variable `T`.

The code in the question doesn't compile for a pretty similar reason. Since the type parameter on `Class` is mainly relevant to methods related to constructors (and in particular the `newInstance` method), we could show an example that's more similar using `Supplier`:

```
static void example(Supplier<? extends Factory<?>> s) {
    capture(s);
}
static <T> void capture(Supplier<? extends Factory<T>> s) {
    Factory<T> a = s.get();
    Factory<T> b = s.get();
    // remember, a and b are supposed to have the same type
    T obj = a.provide();
    b.dispose(obj);
}
```

The problem is that since our supplier could originally be a `Supplier<Factory<?>>`, there's no reason it couldn't, say, return a `Factory<String>` from one invocation and a `Factory<Double>` from another. We therefore shouldn't be able to capture `Supplier<Factory<?>>` to `Supplier<Factory<T>>`. `Class.newInstance` will always return objects of the exact same type, but the compiler doesn't know that.

I think that Eclipse's compiler is probably just wrong in this case to compile the code in the question.

If you want to force this to compile, you *could* use unchecked casts as that user in the comments is suggesting, but I don't know enough about the classes involved to say whether the result of that is actually provably correct. The above two code examples show how doing something like that could actually go horribly wrong (in principle), but `Class` is sometimes a special case.

A way to fix it that's more proper would be to declare a type variable on `bindResourceFactory` so it takes a `Class<? extends Factory<T>>` too, but I don't know if that actually works for the way you're calling the method.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because eclipse uses it's own compiler named ECJ, and maven uses the javac compiler. Sometimes code that compiles in ECJ does not compile in javac and vice versa.

In this particular case the eclipse compiler is able to infer the generic type *T* but javac isn't. So you need to explicity tell the type *T*, which is unknown because the received type is `Class<? extends Factory<?>>`, this means you should use `Object` like the following.

```java
this.<Object>bindFactory((Class<? extends Factory<Object>>) factory);
```

In this case factory needs to be casted, and `this.<Object>` can be ommited because the compiler already infers Object.

Finally you could suppress the cast warning, and it's better to 'uncheck' as little code as possible.

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
Class<? extends Factory<Object>> objFactory = (Class<? extends Factory<Object>>) factory;
bindFactory(objFactory).to(providedClass).in(Singleton.class);
```

One important thing to consider is that the method `getProvidedClass(...)` should return the class correctly

Also the use of generics in the method like this `<T> void bindResourceFactory(Class<? extends Factory<T>>)` would take you to the same place again, because you wouldn't be able to call the method with a class extending `Factory<?>` with a wildcard (`Class<? extends Factory<?>>`).